# Getting the link text or title on Chrome bookmarklets

Tags: html, google-chrome, bookmarklet

Maybe my Chrome is f'ed up but it doesn't play nicely with bookmarklets. I've got HTML(5) like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(...)" title="Drag this into your Bookmarks toolbar">My bookmarklet</a>
```

When I drag it into the bookmarks toolbar it does so without the link text. Or any text. On the bookmarks toolbar I just get a grey globe icon (i.e. not even the site's favicon). I don't want to have to tell my Chrome users to right-click, click Edit... and type in a name.

I've got this in production on [site here](http://toocoolfor.me) if that helps.

Comment: I have the same problem. But I just made a Chrome Extension that does load and call the bookmarklet...

Comment: I get a link text [when I try it](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/Fvqgm/) (Chrome 14.0.835.126 beta), I couldn't see a bookmarklet to test on your site though.  I don't think there's much you can do about the icon, you'd need a link with an actual URL in it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91624#c7) it's a bug with Chrome 13, but it's fixed in Chrome 14.